# Dealing with a very large JSON file

Tags: json, reactjs, firebase

I am making a project that will display a list of "UFO" sightings. I originally was planning to find a API that I could call for this, but was unable too. I did find a rather large JSON file (33mb) with reports of UFO sightings. This JSON file has over a million lines of code in it. What is the best way to use this data? Should I upload it to Firebase database? Break the JSON up into multiple files? I have never dealt with a JSON file this large. After doing research, there seems to be multiple solutions to this. What's the best way to deal with large JSON files in your opinion?

Example of file.

```
{
    "datetime": "10/10/1965 21:00",
    "city": "penarth (uk/wales)",
    "state": "",
    "country": "gb",
    "shape": "circle",
    "duration (seconds)": "180",
    "duration (hours": {
      "min)": "about 3 mins"
    },
    "comments": "penarth uk  circle  3mins  stayed 30ft above me for 3 mins slowly moved of and then with the blink of the eye the speed was unreal",
    "date posted": "2/14/2006",
    "latitude": "51.434722",
    "longitude": -3.18
  },
```

Comment: "What is the best way to use this data?" Questions on "what is best" are notoriously difficult to answer here. We have no idea what you want to do with the data yet. I recommend importing the data into Firebase, and trying to implement the first few use-cases on it. When you get stuck, post back with a concrete problem and it's more likely we can help with that.

Comment: Ok thanks. I want to display the data to the user based on what "state" the user searches for. For example, if the user searched for "New York" it will display all the UFO sighing's in New York.

Comment: Just to provide a bit of perspective, a million lines of code is actually not much data and Firebase (and most databases) can easily handle that - so don't be concerned about the size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say if you import the data in Firebase Realtime Database and then the structure is like:

```
ufos
  |- sight1: {}
  |- sight2: {}
```

For this example let's assume sight 1 is in New York. If your user enters the City as New York then you can easily query it like:

```js
const ufoRef = firebase.database().ref("ufos")
const query = ufoRef.orderByChild("City").equalTo("New York").limitToFirst(20)

query.once("value").then((snapshot) => {
  console.log(snapshot.val())
})
```

This will log first 20 UFO sightings in New York. Unfortunately you can us only 1 equalTo in realtime db so if you want to get sightings in New York at a specific date and duration,  that may not be possible and hence I'll recommend considering Firestore which can perform such queries.

About the size, 33 MB is not something you should worry about. Firebase free quota has 1 GB storage too.

Comment: Dharmaraj,
Thanks for the input! I appreciate it. So you think that i can just pull this json data from memory just fine? basically using a tree structure, i figured it was to much but i suppose i was just assuming, im not sure what "size" is considered to large.

Comment: @meeshaa what do you mean by memory ? Yes you can write some basic queries as in my answer...and 33 mb is fine considering you have so many events.

Comment: Could i potentially just import this json file and loop trough it based on the users input? Or is the file to large and i need to go a different route?

Comment: @meeshaa you don't loop through it... you use queries as mentioned in my answer. Firebase will return das  a that matches your query. Using limit of 20 will return 20 events only so that in no situation is a drawback... just pull required data only. Try to paginate it.

Comment: Perfect thank you.

Comment: @meeshaa glad it was helpful. If you think you've found a decent solution,  you can accept the answer by clicking tick icon. Feel free to ask further questions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235514/discussion-between-meeshaa-and-dharmaraj).